# Is the autocovariance function of a stationary process finite for all lags?

Tags: stationarity

We usually define the autocovariance function of a discrete-time [weak stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Weak_or_wide-sense_stationarity) process as $\gamma(h) := \gamma(h,0) = \gamma(r-s,0) = \gamma(r, s) := \text{Cov}(X_r, X_s)$ with $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Is it possible that for some lags $h \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\gamma({h}) = \infty$ and can an example be provided? I know the variance is always finite ($\gamma(0) < \infty$) but what about for $h \ne 0$?

Comment: You link to a concept usually known as *weak* stationarity.  That's not quite the same as a stationary process, but the difference is enough to call into question your answer.  Please, then, clarify your definition.

Comment: okay, I'll change the name to weak stationarity. Do I need to add the definition for weak stationarity even if I have put up a link?

Comment: You probably don't need to be that explicit, because the term is standard -- but because the answer hinges on the presumption of finite variance, you might wish to point out that the definition includes this assumption.

Comment: Agreed, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is not possible. We know that for stationary processes, $|\gamma(h)| \leq \gamma(0)$, $\forall h \in \mathbb{Z}$ and since $\gamma(0) < \infty$ we are done.

Comment: Consider the case of a stationary process of I.i.d. Cauchy random variables.

Comment: a sequence of Cauchy random variables cannot be stationary because each random variable has [infinite raw second moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Higher_moments)

Comment: And _where_ in the definition of what is meant by a stationary process do you find the restriction that all the random variables have finite second moment? All that stationarity means is that for all choices of positive integer $n$ and $n$ time instants $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n$, the _joint distribution_ of $X(t_1), X(t_2), \ldots, X(t_n)$ is the same as the _joint distribution_ of $X(t_1+\tau), X(t_2+\tau), \ldots, X(t_n+\tau)$, a condition that is easily satisfied by iid random variables regardless of what their common distribution is.

Comment: It's in my question, but I'll place it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Weak_or_wide-sense_stationarity)

Comment: Your link is to the definition of _wide-sense-stationarity_ and not stationarity at all. Stationarity is defined earlier on the same page in Wikipedia, and their definition matches what I said in a previous comment.